# probabilistically segmenting a rectangle

Tags: geometry, random-walk, geometric-probability, probabilistic-method, voronoi-diagram

I am trying to find ways to segment a image randomly, but drawn from a probalistic distribution of pre-determined areas to be cut through. First thought was to pick random points and run [Covex hull algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) to generate the polygons. 
However that still leaves the problem of probabilistically making sure the polygons pass through/segment/cut certain areas as an optimization problem.

I was reminded of [uniform random distribution](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/algorithms/) Birdson's algorithm seemed to have a good idea. Essentially, I'm thinking I can borrow the idea of building from existing samples to form the random points, however, trying to figure out a way to use the preset salient segments for the distribution is stumping me. (distance from the salient parts correlate with probability?) 
Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: @NormalHuman: I just couldn't think of a more fitting tags. Any suggestions?